# Facebook real time inbox messages with Graph API v2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messages

Does anyone know a way to fetch a user/page inbox messages in real time?

I've found [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0), but there is no mention about inbox messages.

Answer (score 0):

The Real-time updates are about... -updates-. That means you will only get notified about changes in the fields described in that link (not regarding the Payments API, that's a different case).

So, you can't get real-time inbox messages.

You can subscribe to the notifications, but I'm not really sure if Messages notifications are included in those...